# How to make a rounded input/dynamic text field in FlashPro CC 2014

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, textfield, flash-cc

You cannot change the text field itself in FlashPro CC 2014. Flash does not allow that.

Is there a way I can make rounded corners on a `TextField` in Flash Pro now?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. If you want to post an answer, first post a question.  You can then answer your own question if you choose.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reskin TextInput component, ddd Flash CC component to stage and look into library. You will see Component Assets group there with all skins. You can edit them to reskin your TextInput.

If you want to have TextField masked by rounded rectangle, you need to... mask TextField with rounded rectangle. =) But remember that you will need to embed your font first, because it will not work with device fonts.

If you are asking about something other, please, specify your problem in details.